# Javascript. Wait for nested fetch promises

Tags: javascript, wordpress, promise, fetch

So i need to use the result of a promise to make another fectch request, i'm working with the rest api for wordpress, and i need the id of subcategories inside the post object to retrieve that category name and build two arrays one with the posts and another with categories names availables.
Here is my function

```
function fetchAccordionData()
{   
    const id = document.querySelector('.acc').getAttribute('data-id'),
          wpRestAPI  = '/wp-json/wp/v2/';
    return fetch(wpRestAPI + 'posts?per_page=100&categories=' + id)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((data) => 
        {
            let curId = [], subCatList = [];
            data.map((post) =>
            {
                let catList = post.categories.filter((c) => c !== parseInt(id));
                fetch(wpRestAPI + 'categories/' + catList[0])
                    .then((r) => r.json())
                    .then((cat) =>
                    {
                        if(!curId.includes(cat.id)) subCatList.push({id: cat.id, name: cat.name});
                        curId.push(cat.id);
                    });
            });
            return {'subCatList':subCatList, 'posts':data}
    });
}
```

Now when i call the function the `subCatList`array isn`t ready yet:

```
fetchAccordionData().then((data) => 
   {
        console.log(data.subCatList, data.posts);
        for(let cat of data.subCatList)
        {
            console.log(cat);
        }
   });
```

So, how do i know when the promise of the second fetch is resolved so i can use the data?

Comment: You're looking for `Promise.all()`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to place all of your promises in an array and use `Promise.all` to wait for all of those promises to resolve before accessing `subCatList`.

Your modified code would look like so:

```
function fetchAccordionData() {   

    const id = document.querySelector('.acc').getAttribute('data-id'),
          wpRestAPI  = '/wp-json/wp/v2/';

    return fetch(wpRestAPI + 'posts?per_page=100&categories=' + id)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((data) => {

            let curId = [], subCatList = [];

            // promises is an array of promises
            let promises = data.map((post) => {

                let catList = post.categories.filter((c) => c !== parseInt(id));

                // return a promise on each iteration
                return fetch(wpRestAPI + 'categories/' + catList[0])
                    .then((r) => r.json())
                    .then((cat) =>
                    {
                        if(!curId.includes(cat.id)) subCatList.push({id: cat.id, name: cat.name});
                        curId.push(cat.id);
                    });
            });

            return Promise.all(promises)
                .then(() => ({'subCatList':subCatList, 'posts':data}));
        });
}
```

Notice that the last step returns the object `{'subCatList': subCatList, 'post': data}` *only* after every promise in `promises` has resolved. That way, you can be confident that the promises in the array are finished making their `push` into `subCatList`.

It's also worth noting that the interface of `fetchAccordionData` stayed exactly the same, so you should be able to use it as you did in your original example:

```
fetchAccordionData().then((data) => {

    console.log(data.subCatList, data.posts);

    for(let cat of data.subCatList) {
        console.log(cat);
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks man! there is just a little issue with the return of the promise.all, it doesn't know that i want an object and can't read the currly braces properly so i had to put the object separately `let r = { 'subCatList' : subCatList, 'posts' : data }; return Promise.all(promises).then(() => r);`

Comment: Woops!  That works, but you might want to try the edited version above, where the expression becomes: `.then(() => ({'subCatList':subCatList, 'posts':data}));` -- notice I wrapped the object around parentheses so that an object is returned. If `subCatList` was a primitive (i.e. a `string`), you would definitely need to create the object after `Promise.all` or your object would contain an outdated value for `subCatList`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
return {'subCatList':subCatList, 'posts':data}
```

is outside of the part of your function that gets categories from the rest API:

```
data.map((post) =>
            {
                let catList = post.categories.filter((c) => c !== parseInt(id));
                fetch(wpRestAPI + 'categories/' + catList[0])
                    .then((r) => r.json())
                    .then((cat) =>
                    {
                        if(!curId.includes(cat.id)) subCatList.push({id: cat.id, name: cat.name});
                        curId.push(cat.id);
                    });
            });
```

so your function is returning it before it can fetch the category data from the API.  If you put your return statement after the last then statement it should return the data your are looking for:

```
data.map((post) =>
            {
                let catList = post.categories.filter((c) => c !== parseInt(id));
                fetch(wpRestAPI + 'categories/' + catList[0])
                    .then((r) => r.json())
                    .then((cat) =>
                    {
                        if(!curId.includes(cat.id)) subCatList.push({id: cat.id, name: cat.name});
                        curId.push(cat.id);
                        return {'subCatList':subCatList, 'posts':data}
                    });
            });
```